# Unity HoloLens force SpatialMapping Update?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

Is it possible to force an Update on the SpatialMapping of the HoloLens in Unity? I've set the "Time between Updates" to 0.5 seconds in both Spatial Mapping Collider and Spatial Mapping Renderer but that doesn't work well.

Basically what I want is to implement the Tap gesture to update the spatial mapping the same way it is done in the Microsoft Holographic Shell. For my application, it is very crucial that raycast along the gaze vector finds a surface in the fastest way.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

No, not really this article might help to understand and provide you with a way to do what you want to do. But not in the way that you are suggesting.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/the-truth-about-fixedupdate.231637/

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question a bit - I'm not talking about doing something in the Update() or FixedUpdate() steps, but enforce an "information update" of the SpatialMapping Collider/Renderer via Tap Gesture, for example:

`InteractionManager.SourcePressed += (s) => { //enforce wireframe update here }`

Comment: I don't think so, but you might want to pose the question on the hololens developer forums, and the mods and hololens developer would likely have a better answer than me.

Comment: Thanks! BTW: I figured out that the update of the SpatialMapping works much faster and better when compiling in Release mode ;) Almost good enough..